# How to register Android ContentObserver for constant monitoring?

Tags: android, contentobserver

I am trying to add functionality to my app to monitor the app's database (via `MyContentProvider`) for new items. So I've create a `MyContentObserver` which, as new items are added to the database, will:

1. Update the badge/counter on the app's launcher icon with the number of new items.
2. Store that same integer in **SharedPreferences**, so it can be accessed by other components of the app (e.g., by Activities/Fragments to display on their UI, and by `MyApplication` to set the app icon's badge/counter when the device reboots).

I have tried registering `MyContentObserver` in the `onCreate()` method of `MyApplication`, but it does not seem to be a reliable way of doing it.

Whilst trying to research the correct way of doing it, I've seen some SO posts describing how some developers have tried implementing a **Service** (instead of `MyApplication`) to meet the objective, but most of these developers are also citing problems.

As there does not appear to be a guide anywhere on this, can someone recommend the proper way to set up a **ContentObserver** for it to monitor constantly and dependably?

Comment: If you're writing your `MyContentProvider`, then you know exactly when to update the `SharedPreferences`, etc. - right as you do an operation. Why would you need a separate `ContentObserver` for that?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Good point, thanks. Maybe I will have to go that route, but I would prefer to keep this functionality apart from `MyContentProvider`, if possible - esp. as I may need to do this for external content providers in the future.